# Unable to Logout after android Facebook Login

Tags: android

```
    public void logoutFromFacebook() {

    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"LogOut Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}
```

after login if i click logout button unable to logout and while once again pressing login button get session true.How can I get logout from here so that another user can login using his/her facebook id.

Answer (score 1):

For logut use:

import com.facebook.Session;
....

Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();

Comment: The method getActiveSession() is undefined for the type SpellCheckerService.Session.......showing the above error

Comment: are you importing correct class? import com.facebook.Session;

Answer (score 1):

```
 import com.facebook.Session;

  private void logout()
    {
        // clear any user information
        mApp.clearUserPrefs();

        // find the active session which can only be facebook in my app
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        // run the closeAndClearTokenInformation which does the following
        // DOCS : Closes the local in-memory Session object and clears any persistent 
        // cache related to the Session.
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();

        // return the user to the login screen
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));

        // make sure the user can not access the page after he/she is logged out
        // clear the activity stack
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: same issues like previous one

Comment: import com.facebook.Session in your class

Comment: while importing import com.facebook.Session; get error

Comment: Use latest Facebook SDK for Android
Refer this Logout Flow link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate#step3

Comment: I downloaded from there but get some error while importing it like gen folder missing

Comment: Clean your Project and Restart your IDE.

Comment: FacebookSDK] Unable to resolve target 'android-9' change the target also

Comment: Check your build path